# Python, Permission denied only when dragging folder onto script

Tags: python, windows, file, permission-denied

I have a script that is supposed to read a directory from its second argument and do various processes on it, and record the information to a second file, `compressed.xml`. Here's the code that causes errors:

```
targetpath = os.getcwd()
if len(sys.argv) >= 2:
    targetpath = sys.argv[1]

with open("compressed.xml", "w") as f:
    base = ntpath.basename(targetpath)
    f.write("<" + base + ">\n")
    f.write(getXML(targetpath, 1))
    f.write("</" + base + ">\n")
```

When I run the script on the command line with a directory path as an argument, it works perfectly fine. But if I try to drag a folder onto the script from within File Explorer, it causes a "permission denied" error on `compressed.xml`. I can't really get more information about the traceback than that, because I don't really know how to get more info about it than using this simple catch;

```
except Exception as e:
    raw_input(e)
```

Without it, the shell closes instantly upon causing an error, and I'm not able to see the traceback.

Comment: If you want to see the traceback, [do this](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3114f99c9606387c3834)

Comment: The traceback it prints out using that method doesn't give much more information. However, I can't seem to copy it directly from the window, and attempting to write a line like this; `with open("err.txt", "w") as errout: errout.write(traceback.format_exc())` just ends up causing a second stacktrace, which closes the window immediately and I'm unable to read it.

Comment: You're creating compressed.xml in the working directory. What's the working directory when dropping a file on the script? I'd think you'd want it beside the target, e.g. `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(targetpath), 'compressed.xml')`.

Comment: BTW, use `os.path`. It's `ntpath` for Windows and `posixpath` for POSIX.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. But you ought to have posted that as an answer, instead of a comment.